# Git doesn't look in HOME directory for .gitconfig when making global settings

Tags: git, windows-10

When I run

```
Get-Variable HOME
```

I get

> C:\Users\DonkeyButt

which is my user's root directory. However, for some reason, placing the *.gitconfig* file there makes no difference to behavior and I noticed that it seem like Git doesn't look at that spot at all.

Furthermore, when I set global values like

```
git config --global user.email donkey@butt.com
```

it's being stored in *.gitconfig* which is located in *H:*. It's Win 10 machine that a company configured for me but me being local admin and them not being excessively intrusive or corporatish, I doubt it's got any significance.

How can I make Git obey? Googling the issue leads to a bunch of posts saying that *HOME* needs to be set properly. That helps not.

Comment: Please run `set` in the command line tool where you invoke `git config` and post the output of `HOME`, `HOMEDRIVE`, and `HOMEPATH`. Literal output is needed, not some transliteration.

Comment: @j6t Not sure if it's  a typo or me missing something. The command *set* is alias for *Set-Variable* and I sense that you mean the opposite - getting, which is done by *Get-Variable*. Running the latter gives me *HOME* as stated in the question, *HOMEDRIVE* and *HOMEPATH* produce an error. However, running just *Get-Variable* without parameters shows that they are *H* and */* respectively, so you might be onto something. Strange that it happened.

Comment: So, you invoke `git config ...` from the same command line-thing where you invoke `Get-Variable`? Is that PowerShell? If you do not see `HOMEDRIVE` or `HOMEPATH` then your `Get-Variable` does not read the environment variables (and it is no surprise that `git` reads something different), or your setup is severly damaged.